# Making a calculated field on a calculated field (Excel 2016)

Tags: excel

I'm having some weird results with calculated fields.
The Pivot table I'm using is as below:

[image: Pivot table]

The column I'm having problems with is the last one, it subtracts "WEIGTH" from "CURRENT MRP REORDERPOINT". As you can see I get a weird result at line 20.
Anyone know what could be going wrong here?

Extra info:

[image: Calculated field of Weight]
[image: Calculated field of Change]

"CURRENT MRP REORDERPOINT" has been set as `MIN` in Summarize value by.
If you need any more info, I'll be happy to supply.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are mutliple records being grouped?  Notice that the problem field is called `Sum of Change`, but you have only included formulas for `Round` and *half* of the formula for `Change` but no `Sum of Change`.  This implies that it's adding more than one record.

Comment: The easiest way to fix it is probably to just remove *all* the formulas (maybe copy the data-only to a new workbook) and start fresh. It should take 2 minutes to recreate the formulas from scratch and then you'll know exactly what they are referring to.   Also, a few tips, check out how to create a [mcve] and also see "[ask]" as well as [these great tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) from [so]'s top user...  and, Welcome!

Comment: @ashleedawg The sum comes automatically since it is a value field in the pivot table, I tried min or max to set it to 1 value only, but that gave exactly the same result